How can I set the correct app title to display on macos with avalonia?
Is there a way to get the correct app title on the mac with Avalonia (see image)?

It says Avalonia Application instead of the Application name. Is there a way to change that? It seems that I have to write more text even though my intention should be clear already so I keep on writing until the algorithm accepts it.

Set the Title property of the Window.

To set the title of a window, there is a property (usually preset with the name of the window itself) in the declaration of the window.
In the above line, you can also change the application's icon
Here is an example
If it doesn't work even like this, try going to the App.Axaml class and adding:

<Application Name=". . ." >


Code excerpts, like the one showing a Title attribute being added to a Window node, are best pasted into a question or answer in a text-block, delimited by triple-back-ticks, rather than being embedded as an image.
